# Identity column is not applied to the database

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a class 'BudgetDetail' like this:

```
public class BudgetDetail
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Budget Budget{ get; set; }
    public int BudgetId { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public byte Quantity { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public int Iva { get; set; }
    public int Total { get; set; }
}
```

And this is the Fluent API configuration for this model:

```
public class BudgetDetailConfiguration: EntityTypeConfiguration<BudgetDetail>
{
    public BudgetDetailConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("BudgetDetails");

        HasKey(pd => new { pd.Id, pd.BudgetId, pd.ProductId });

        Property(pd => pd.Id)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
    }
}
```

And when I made the migration, the identity of the Id property is setting to true but if I look in the database the identity it is set to false and I don't know why, I guess it is because I have composite keys to this table.

Identity column doesn't work if you have composite keys?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but a composite key including an identity doesn't make sense. You only need the identity column for it to be unique. Adding the other columns is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

You have a BudgetId and a Budget - same for Product. Adding both does not mean they are related. The Budget object is unrelated to the BudgetId - the BudgetDetails class has two different attributes - one if  BudgetId (FK) and one is an actual Budget object.

Remove your objects and keep their PKs - which are FKs within the BudgetDetail class.

```
public class BudgetDetail
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    // public Budget Budget{ get; set; }
    public int BudgetId { get; set; }
    // public Product Product { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    .../...
}
```